# Publish micrometer metrics programatically

Tags: timer, histogram, micrometer

I'm using micrometer (https://micrometer.io/) to measure latency in calls to several remote endpoints. I want to publish a histogram over latency to a logfile after my test run finish. Is that possible to publish such programatically?

```
// Setup metrics

var loggingRegistry = LoggingMeterRegistry()
Metrics.addRegistry(loggingRegistry)

Timer.builder("remote.call")
    .publishPercentiles(0.3, 0.5, 0.95)
    .publishPercentileHistogram() 
    .register(Metrics.globalRegistry)
```

Many remote calls...

```
  Metrics.timer("remote.call", "endpoint", endpointTag).recordCallable {
            // the remote call to different endpoints...
            remoteCall()
        }
```

As a default micrometer is publishing a histogram every one minute. Is there a way to publish the histogram programatically instead?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `loggingRegistry.publish()` will trigger a publish.

Internally the registry us a 'StepMeterRegistry' because it chunks metrics by step (as in minute) and publishing won't change the step or reset it. So keep that in mind.